# How to carry out a counter number in parallel_for_each

Tags: c++-amp

1)Why  the variable length in my sample code are not 62 after calculate ?  It's
  seems every time the condition is satisfied,but enter the condition, 
  the number "length not be added every single time.

2)If I don't use concurrency::array length(1, 1, &V[0]); to save counter
  but using tile_static int, the length is also wrong.

```
//if my 8 x 8 local data are:
//cache[TS][TS] 
//{
//  -69, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
//    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
//}
```

My sample code:

```
void sample()
{

    std::vector<int> V;
    V.push_back(0);
    concurrency::array<int, 2> length(1, 1, &V[0]); 

    const int TS = 8;
    concurrency::parallel_for_each(data.extent.tile<TS, TS>(), [=, &length](tiled_index<TS, TS> index) restrict(amp)
    {
        const int row = index.local[0];
        const int col = index.local[1];

        //tile_static int length; ---------2)
        tile_static  int cache[TS][TS];
        cache[row][col] = data[index.global];
        index.barrier.wait();

        if (cache[row][col] == 0)
        {
            //length++; -------------------2)
            length[0][0] = length[0][0] + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The following operation cannot be thread safe without further protection `length[0][0] = length[0][0] + 1;`  I didn't read enough about `concurrency::array` to see even if the point of it includes making some operations thread safe (that would not be in a simpler array).  But there is nothing it could do about that one.  So each time that line overlaps across two threads, best case is you lose one count.

Comment: Firstly, thanks your answer, but even if I don'y use concurrency:array to save my counter but using tile_static int or int to save it. It's all unworkable.
EX:  tile_static int length;    if (cache[row][col] == 0){ length++;} So there is nothing to do about saving counter numbers in parallel_for_each??

Comment: using for loop seems  ok, but it's only one work around solution??  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
 {
  if (cache[i][j] == 0)
  {
   len++;
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    std::vector<int> V;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        V.push_back(0);

    concurrency::array_view<int, 1> AC_count(256, &V[0]);

    const int TS = 8;
    concurrency::parallel_for_each(data.extent.tile<TS, TS>(), [=, &length](tiled_index<TS, TS> index) restrict(amp)
    {
        const int row = index.local[0];
        const int col = index.local[1];

        tile_static  int cache[TS][TS];
        cache[row][col] = data[index.global];
        index.barrier.wait();

        if (cache[row][col] == 0)
        {
            atomic_fetch_add(&AC_count[0], 1);
        }
    });
}
```